# Euler's Method for slope fields

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I tried to do euler's method with this problem:
$$\frac{dw}{dt} = (3-w)(w+1),\quad w(0) = 0,\quad \text{and }t\in [0,5].\quad \Delta t = 0.5.$$

But am getting weird results like for $y_2 = 5.25$, $y_3= -15.84375$;
but checked against the book but this is not correct. Can you please work out some iterations?

$y_2 = 1.5 + (3-1.5)(1.5+1)(1) = 5.25$, for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Euler's method in this case is
$
  y_{k+1} = y_k + \Delta t \cdot (3-y_k)(y_k+1)
$, $y_0=0$. This gives $y_2 = 3.375$ and $y_3=2.555$. Note that $\Delta t = 0.5$.